# Power and sample size estimations, how to standardize and compare to previous research. MLR or Correlation for effect size?

Tags: r, multiple-regression, sample-size, effect-size, statistical-power

Ok, there are a couple of questions here to be honest,

Background: I am assessing if thinking,(INFP (Likert scale, 4 subscales) and CT (Likert, two subscales) predict (other-rated) perceptions of behaviourA (likert, two scales: behaviourAa & behaviour Ac) and (other-rated) perceptions of behaviourB. Im also looking at whether (other-rated) perceptions of behaviourAa and behaviour Ac predict (other-rated) perceptions of behaviourB.

Method: Correlations to assess strength and direction of relationships. Multiple regression for analysis 1, a hierarchical multiple regression for analysis 2, 2 multiple regressions for analysis 3.

Results: largely contradictory to prior research. Analysis 1: only one thinking scale predicts behaviourB. Analysis 2: One thinking style predicts behaviour B in step 1, step 2 increased variance explained and behaviourAa predicts behaviourB. Third analysis indicated that one thinking style predicts behaviourAc but nothing significant between thinking and behaviourAa.

Sample size was N = 160 (matched pairs), 8 predictor variables in the main hierarchical regression model. A sensitivity power test suggested that the minimum detectable effect size was F2 = .09. 
When looking at previous research, I am unsure how to report and present the effect sizes reported by others. I cant seem to find any decent examples in the literature.

Also, major problems are:

1, previous literature have reported Adjusted R2, not R2 and there are no SE reported. None of the related studies have reported effect sizes but instead just Standardised Coefficients and Adjusted R2. Hence, is there a way for me to convert the stats to effect sizes? and observed power.

2, Previous literature have reported the total finding e.g Thinking scale A, thinking scale B, thinking scale C predicted BehaviourB, (this is not what I found and is there hence any way of breaking the results down? or does that not make sense to do?

3, I have three studies that have looked at the relationship between thinking and behaviourB. 3 studies that have looked at behaviourAa and behaviourAc and behaviourB.and I have 1 study which assessed thinking and behaviourAa and behaviourAc. How do I report the ins and outs with them noting I only have few studies to comment on, is it still worthwhile to do some sort of pooling of averages to report previous literature's effect sizes (to justify sample size).

4, If so, what stats program / online calculator do I need/ use for pooling regression results (noting that although previous literature measured the same predictors they used specific subsets in their models (which I haven't since my measure is the revised measure (and has additional subscales not previously tested).

5, Would it make sense to report something about effect sizes of correlations instead?

6, Am i missing something here?

I feel like I have read everything that is out there and I am just getting more and more confused. Oh and also, last little note. Im on a Mac which means I cant access all stats programs and Im far from a wizz when it comes to R..